# change /update records angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(customerData, index) {
   //$scope.customers.push(customerData);
    $scope.customers[index] = customerData;
});
```

I want to change / update existing Json record by using angularjs. i.e.  I want to edit the values at index 2 and also refresh the data table

Answer (score 0):

So, I would think that on the HTML side you are using ng-repeat, if so this will catch the indexing for you.  Angular uses two way data binging.  So if you are using inputs, and ng-model, this should update the specific item in the table.

From there you just need to post to the database on the back end if you are saving these changes.